# How to use Restrictions in Hibernate 5.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

From Hibernate 5 Create criteria has been deprecated. Instead we can use Create query. But how to add restrictions now. Please anyone help me with this

```
public List<ExpensesSummary> displayExpense() {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder builer = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ExpensesSummary> criteria = builer.createQuery(ExpensesSummary.class);
    List<ExpensesSummary> expensesList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    return expensesList;
}
```

Comment: You can use CriteriaBuilder methods for restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example, may help you.

```
         final CriteriaBuilder builder = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
         CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Customer.class);
         Root<Customer> Customer = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);     
         criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(builder.upper(customer.get("customerName")),customerName.toUpperCase()));
         Query<Customer> query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
         final List<Customer> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: @Yuvanath Is this example help for your solution

Comment: So we cant use .Restrictions in Hibernate 5 and above ??

Comment: If you use CriteriaBuilder then no, but in old criteria way you can still use Restriction APIs which are depicted in Hibernate5

Comment: In Hibernate 5.1.3.Final Criteria is not deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`Session.getCriteriaBuilder()` method is inherited from [`javax.persistence.EntityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html?is-external=true#getCriteriaBuilder--) interface. So criteria building is done accoriding to JPA standard.

You can check on this resource for JPA reference: [WHERE in Criteria Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/where#WHERE_in_Criteria_Queries_)

Answer (score 0):

Example for CriteriaBuilder with restrictions of CriteriaBuilder methods. The JPQL for this Criteria.

```
select i from Item i where i.name="SomeThing"
```

Now with CriteriaBuilder...

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery criteria = builder.createQuery();
    Root<Item> i = criteria.from(Item.class);
    criteria.select(i).where(
            builder.equal(i.get("name"), "SomeThing")
    );

    TypedQuery<Role> query = session.createQuery(criteria);
```

Now you can get the result from the query by getSingleResult() or getResultList(). and if you want to know about more restriction methods of CriteriaBuilder [Click Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjivi/index.html).